# insertRow not working in for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

```
$(function(){
  $('#sizePicker').submit(function makeGrid(evt) {
    $('#pixel_canvas').empty();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var row = $('#input_height').val();
    var cell = $('#input_width').val();
    var table = $('#pixel_canvas');
    for(r = 0; r <= row; r++){
        var addRow = table.insertRow(r)
        for(c = 0; c <= cell; c++){
            addRow.insertCell(c);
        }
    }
  });
});
```

This is my code to add rows and cells based on input, but for some reason when I use .insertRow and .insertCell there's no output, but when I use .append the function works perfectly. Anyone know why?

Comment: table is a jquery element, not a dom element. do table.get(0).insertRow(r)

Answer (score 0):

You are treating table like it's in the dom but it is a jQuery element so that wouldn't work.

Try this

```
table.get(0).insertRow(r)
```